# Proper time to cast vs. convert in c#

Tags: c#, casting

So I've always assumed that casting and converting in c# are basically the same thing:  Two different ways to go from one data type to another.  Clearly this is incorrect though since they often will output different results.

```
Convert.ToInt32(1.6)     //outputs 2
(Int32)1.6               //outputs 1


(DateTime)("10/29/2013")          //won't compile - cannot convert type 'string' to type 'system.date.time'
Convert.ToDateTime("10/29/2013")  //outputs 10/29/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

- My question is what is the primary difference between the two and why do they return different results?
- What is the 'appropriate' time to use one over the other?

Personally I find myself using the `Convert.To` method as that seems cleaner to me.  I know that it also throws the `System.InvalidCastException`.    Can anyone provide a straightforward explanation?

Comment: `Convert` does a little bit of "magic" when converting. It analyses the value of the source type and applies transformation to create a new instance of the target type. Casting happens on a lower level, and you can only cast related types (e.g. a floating point number to an integral number).

Comment: @Kelix Your examples answer your own questions. Generally, casting should be used when you have inheritance. Use Convert to transform one thing to another thing when you cannot cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cast in two cases:

- when type you are casting to IS a type you are casting from
- when [explicit cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defined for these types

In all other cases you should use Convert or other custom conversion method (e.g. DateTime.Parse).

> why do they return different results?

Because different code is executed. `Convert.ToInt32(double value)` rounds result of casting:

```
int num = (int) value;
double num2 = value - num;
if ((num2 > 0.5) || ((num2 == 0.5) && ((num & 1) != 0)))    
    num++;

return num;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your conversion the [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303w38b8.aspx) method uses the following rules for its return value

> value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is
>   halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that
>   is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

However the rules for the [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288039%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are different

> When you convert a decimal value to an integral type, this value is
>   rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If the resulting
>   integral value is outside the range of the destination type, an
>   OverflowException is thrown.

If you want the cast to operate the same as the `Convert.ToInt32` [or want to specify how the rounding would work] then you should use the [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with a cast as follows.

```
(int)Math.Round(1.6) //outputs 2
```

There are other method signatures which allow you to specify how to Round as well.

As far as when you should use cast and convert, you should use the [explicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691288%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) when possible *realizing that you are going to lose precision when going from a more precise to less precise type and handling it appropriately* and the convert when the data is not expected to be in a format that can be cast.  **when possible** means when explicit conversion (including implicit conversions) exists.  The pre-defined conversions can be found in [Section 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691279%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the spec

> A cast-expression of the form (T)E, where T is a type and E is a
>   unary-expression, performs an explicit conversion (Section 6.2) of the
>   value of E to type T. If no explicit conversion exists from the type
>   of E to T, a compile-time error occurs. Otherwise, the result is the
>   value produced by the explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fast rule on which to use in all cases.  You just have to know what each does and pick the one that's most appropriate for your scenario.  Like yourself have pointed out, Convert and cast can produce different results.  The reason is Convert and cast can have totally different implenentations.

```
public static explicit operator MyStructA(MyStructB b)  
{
    MyStructA a = convert.ToMyStructA(b); 
    //I could do this so that convert and cast return the same but I don't have to.

    return a;
}
```